# Handling Exceptions within @Transactional Class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Within my Spring-managed class (`@Transactional` and `@Service` annotations), I have the following method:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class Foo {

    @Autowired
    private MyService service; // MyService has @Service and @Transactional annotations


      public void save(...) { 
          try { 
              service.save(...); // gets a Hibernate Session & calls `merge(...)`
          } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
             logMessage("save failed with exception: " + e);
          }
      }
```

In my corresponding table (for which `Foo#save` does the work of saving), I have a `unique constraint`.

When the above `Foo#save` code executes in such a way that the unique constraint is violated, I see in my log that a `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown, but it's not being caught by my `Foo#save`'s `catch` block.

```
   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager 891 doRollbackOnCommitException - 
     Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception 
   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute 
       JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into MY_TABLE ...; constraint 
         [MY_CONSTRAINT]; nested exception is 
       org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute 
    JDBC batch update
```

Confused that the `DataIntegrityViolationException` was not being caught, I added another catch for all `RuntimeException`'s:

```
      public save(...) { 
          try { 
              service.save(...); // `service` is marked with 
                                 //  @Service and @Transactional
          } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
             logMessage("save failed with exception: " + e);
          } catch(RuntimeException e) {
             logMesssage("runtime exception e: " + e);
          }
      }
```

But, again, when I ran the same code that would violate the unique constraint violation, I did not see the log message from the `catch(RuntimeException e)` block.

My incomplete understanding is that, since I'm using `@Transactional`, a proxy of `Foo` (created by Spring) will perform the `save` method call.

But, is it possible for me to catch the `DataIntegrityViolationException` called by `service.save(...)`?

Comment: what spring verion you are using?

Comment: The transaction runs around your service method. The commit will take place AFTER the method executed. Basically your catch block, no matter how much exceptions you catch, is useless here. You need to catch the exception in the layer/class that is calling this one.

Comment: Thanks.  Carre to post for credit? Also could you post a docs link reference with your answer?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-decl-explained

Answer (score 1):

Method `session.merge(...)` does not immediatelly executes an insert/update SQL query, but put this action in a queue. SQL query will be executed when session flushed. In your case session will be flushed in transactional advice after your method executes, and exception will be thrown there. 
So to catch exception in your method add `session.flush()` after `session.merge(...)` like so:

```
  public class MyService {

      public void save(Object o) {
         Session session = //get session somehow
         session.merge(o);
         session.flush();  // In case of data integrity violation Exception will be thrown here
      }
  }
```